# How to get rid of this problem in Terminal MacOS? No such file or directory whenever I open Terminal 

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, homebrew, reset

After using Terminal for a long time, I get this whenever I open Terminal, and it's really annoying for me to see this mess. Can someone help me with making Terminal back to the time when I first opened it (like at the beginning when you just bought your new laptop)?

This is what I get whenever I just open Terminal:

```
/Users/seannie/.zshrc:source:17: no such file or directory: /Users/seannie/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
/Users/seannie/.zshrc:source:18: no such file or directory: /Users/seannie/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
/Users/seannie/.zshrc:19: command not found: chruby
/Users/seannie/.zshrc:source:20: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
/Users/seannie/.zshrc:source:21: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
/Users/seannie/.zshrc:22: command not found: chruby
```

I tried some commands, but they didn't work for me. Maybe I need clearer guidelines

Comment: It's telling you that at one point `chruby` was available and now it isn't. Did you copy your .zshrc configuration file from somebody else? Did you uninstall `chruby`? Did you migrate your homebrew installation somewhere else?

Comment: If you used home-brew to install try the reinstall option.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `~/.zshrc` to remove the lines referencing those files.

```bash
open -e ~/.zshrc
```

In the TextEdit window find lines 17-22 and delete them. Save the file, then close TextEdit. Restart your Terminal to verify the problem is resolved.

Alternatively, you can remove the lines from the command line:

```bash
sed -i.bak '17,22d' ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I guess you're less paranoid than I am. I would comment the lines rather than delete them until I was darned sure that there weren't secondary effects to having `chruby` evaporate.

Comment: Worst-case scenario involves [adding it back](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#configuration). The misconfiguration is pretty clear from the errors.